# Show $I_1-I_2=\frac 1 8$ for $I_n = \int_{0}^{1} {}x^n\sqrt[3]{3x^2-2x^3}dx$

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals

> Show $I_1-I_2=\frac 1 8$ for $$I_n = \int_{0}^{1} {}x^n\sqrt[3]{3x^2-2x^3}dx$$

I've tried to get some hints with the help of some integral calculation sites but it seems that they can't find an answer.

Comment: but your integral leads to a hypergeometric series

Comment: The integral is a 12th grade level exercise on the college exam....

Comment: hm and there is no typo in it?

Comment: No, I triple-checked. Also the difficulty is marked as easy to medium.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Over thinking it much?  :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**HINT**

$$I_1-I_2= \int_{0}^{1} (x-x^2)\sqrt[3]{3x^2-2x^3}dx$$

Sub $t=3x^2-2x^3$, $dt=6(x-x^2)dx$.

Comment: this is a good hint

Comment: Solved it, thx :)